# Reset Excel "Find and Replace" dialog box parameters

Tags: excel, vba

How do I programmatically reset the Excel `Find and Replace` dialog box parameters to defaults ("Find what", "Replace with", "Within", "Search", "Look in", "Match case", "Match entire cell contents")?

I am using `Application.FindFormat.Clear` and `Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear` to reset find and replace cell formats.

Interestingly, after using `expression.Replace(FindWhat, ReplaceWhat, After, MatchCase, WholeWords)`, the `FindWhat` string shows in the `Find and Replace` dialog box but not the `ReplaceWhat` parameter.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this macro to reset find & replace.  Unfortunately, you have to call them both as there are one or two arguments unique to each, so if you want to reset everything, you're stuck.  There is no 'reset', so the only way I have found is to execute a fake find & replace using the default parameters.

```
Sub ResetFind()
    Dim r As Range

    On Error Resume Next  'just in case there is no active cell
    Set r = ActiveCell
    On Error Goto 0

    Cells.Find what:="", _
               After:=ActiveCell, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace what:="", Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False

    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Select
    Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to open the "Replace" dialog with fields filled:

**Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaReplace).Show -arguments here-**

the argument list is

find_text, replace_text, look_at, look_by, active_cell, match_case, match_byte

---

So far, the only way I've found to 'click' the buttons is with SendKey.

---

After much research and testing, I now know exactly what you want to do, but don't think it can be done (without SendKey).  It appears that there is a bug in Excel, that won't reset the replacement value (from VBA), no matter what you try and set it to.

I did find this 'faster' way someone posted on MSDN, so you might give it a try.

[**Faster than Replace**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/293217af-6c12-4ed2-9021-8eefa71aa98a/)

Comment: Thanks very much. Am looking to clean up after using Find and Replace in VBA. Would have liked a solution which didn't necessitate popping up the dialog box. Didn't know about the parameters after the Show method. At least saves me from using SendKeys (brute force). Johannesburg, South Africa.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use sendkeys you can easily refer to the values you need to reset the dialog box values.

```
Sub ResetFindReplace()
   'Resets the find/replace dialog box options
   Dim r As Range

   On Error Resume Next

   Set r = Cells.Find(What:="", _
   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
   SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
   LookAt:=xlPart, _
   MatchCase:=False)

   On Error GoTo 0

   'Reset the defaults

   On Error Resume Next

   Set r = Cells.Find(What:="", _
   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
   SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
   LookAt:=xlPart, _
   MatchCase:=False)

   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works. I have borrowed parts from a few places

```
Sub RR0()   'Replace Reset & Open dialog  (specs: clear settings, search columns, match case)

'Dim r As RANGE         'not seem to need
'Set r = ActiveCell     'not seem to need
On Error Resume Next    'just in case there is no active cell
On Error GoTo 0

Application.FindFormat.Clear          'yes
Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear       'yes

Cells.find what:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext
Cells.Replace what:="", Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False, MatchCase:=True    'format not seem to do anything
'Cells.Replace what:="", Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False    'orig, wo matchcase not work unless put here - in replace

'If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Select    'not seem to need
'Set r = Nothing

'settings choices:
'match entire cell:  LookAt:=xlWhole,  or:  LookAt:=xlPart,
'column or row:      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,  or:  SearchOrder:=xlByRows,

Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Replace...").Execute   'YES WORKS
'Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Find...").Execute   'YES same, easier to manipulate
'Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1849).Execute        'YES full find dialog

'PROBLEM: how to expand options?
'SendKeys ("%{T}")   'alt-T works the first time, want options to stay open

Application.EnableEvents = True           'EVENTS

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dave Parillo's solution is very good but it does not reset the formatting options of Excel's Find an Replace dialog. The following is more thorough and does reset those options.

```
Sub ResetFindAndReplace()
    Dim oldActive As Range, oldSelection As Range
    On Error Resume Next  ' just in case there is no active cell
    Set oldActive = ActiveCell
    Set oldSelection = Selection
    On Error GoTo 0   
    Cells.Find what:="", _
               After:=ActiveCell, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace what:="", Replacement:="", ReplaceFormat:=False
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' return selection cell
    If Not oldSelection Is Nothing Then oldSelection.Select 
    ' return active cell
    If Not oldActive Is Nothing Then oldActive.Activate
    Set oldActive = Nothing
End Sub
```